# Why is the 1,6 linkage in Amylopectin an alpha link and not a beta link?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

[image]

The alpha link as I have understood it means that the $\ce{OH}$ molecules which make up the glycosidic bond lie on the same side of(above/ below) the plane and for beta, one lies above the plane and the other below it.

For the 1,6 linkage in Amylopectin, one $\ce{OH}$ group lies below the plane and the $\ce{CH3OH}$ group lies below the plane. Then why is the 1,6 link in amylopectin not an alpha linkage?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me and in danger of being closed. Amylopectin has alpha linkages. If the linkage were beta, amylopectin would not be digestible by humans.

Comment: The 1,6 bond in amylopectin is labeled as alpha link and it looks similar to the Beta links of cellulose. (One OH below the plane and one OH above the plane. I am talking of those OH condensed to make the glycosidic link.) So i am unable to understand how the 1,6 link in amylopectin is labelled as alpha as it very much resembles the Beta nature.

Comment: "OH molecule"? Amylope**n**tin? *is* 1,6 link *is*? I understand that *articles* are difficult if you don´t come from a indoeuropean language, but this is embarassing. The effort people put into their answers is usually directly proportional to the effort you put into writing up your question!

Comment: The title and body of the question contradict each other, making it difficult to take it seriously.

Comment: Actually I didnt understand the meaning of alpha link correctly previously. I now undertsand that when two alpha anomers make up a link its called alpha link ; same for beta; and if alpha and beta make up the link its called alpha - beta. Although i previously knew what alpha anomer means i was confusing it with the meaning of what alpha link means. Anyways i have got it cleared up now.

Comment: Alpha and beta refers to the stereochemistry at the anomeric carbon. The 4 and 6 positions in glucose are not anomeric, and there is only one way to link them. So you have to look at the 1 position that is part of the glycosidic bond. Sucrose has a alpha-1, beta-2 linkage (both glucose and fructose form a glycosidic bond involving their respective anomeric carbon).

Answer (score 5):

You seem to be having trouble with the terms alpha and beta and how to recognize these terms in carbohydrates. Here is an easy way to recognize them when they are drawn in the conventional way shown below.. In a Fischer projection of glucopyranose,  for example, the hydroxyl group in the *beta* anomer is on the *left*; the **alpha** anomer is on the **right**. [Notice that the italicized terms have fewer letters than the bold terms!] In the Haworth projection and the chair conformation of glucopyranose the terms *beta*, *top* and *up* have fewer letters than their respective terms **alpha**, **bottom** and **down** in the other anomer. 
Amateur sailors use the same mnemonic to remember that the *port* is on the *left* (*red* light) side of the boat and that the **starboard** is on the **right** (**green** light).

[image]
Source: [http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/carbohydrates44.pdf](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/carbohydrates44.pdf)

Comment: Actually I didnt understand the meaning of alpha link correctly previously. I now undertsand that when two alpha anomers make up a link its called alpha link ; same for beta; and if  alpha and beta make up the link its called alpha - beta. Although i previously knew what alpha anomer means i was confusing it with the meaning of what alpha link means. Thanks.

Comment: @user55119 In my opinion you should mention that the method is valid when numbering of carbon is done in clockwise direction to make method unambiguous. eg: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/43546/108386